# Converting .net4.0 old library to multiple targets with .net standard 2.0 gives HtmlString reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-standard

I'm porting an old class library so it can multi target both .net4.0 and .net standard. I need to use the same library on a .net core project.

The library relies heavily on `System.Web.Mvc` and I'm using the Strategy 1 described here:
[Upgrading ASP.NET Libraries to .NET Standard](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/347/upgrading-asp-net-libraries-to-net-standard)

The errors I couldn't solve are:

> 1 - Reference to type 'HtmlString claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could no be found
>   [image: It looks like this on VS2017:]
>
> 2 - 'MvcHtmlString' does not contain a definition for 'ToHtmlString' and no extension method 'ToHtmlString' accepting a first argument of type 'MvcHtmlString' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   [image: It looks like this on VS2017:]

I created a new .net standard class library project and copied the files over. This is my csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net40</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" Version="3.0.50813.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net40' ">     
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I tried adding this to `netstandard2.0` ItemGroup but it didn't help:

```
<Reference Include="System.Web" />
```

What do I need to do to fix? I've read some about the subject, but it's still confusing and the links I found didn't help.

---

I ended up using a new code base only for `.NET Core`.
My `.csproj` is like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.DataAnnotations" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

As @NightOwl888 explained, I needed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions` so I could use `HtmlString` instead of `MvcHtmlString`.

The `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures` is necessary so the `SelectExtensions` like `DropDownListFor` for example could return a type compatible with `HtmlString`.

I also had to replace all `HtmlHelper` with `IHtmlHelper` and `ModelMetaData` with `ModelExplorer`.

`ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression` is now `ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [article you linked](https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/347/upgrading-asp-net-libraries-to-net-standard):

> Provided that the library does not invoke any functionality that is beyond what is available in .NET Standard 2.0, compatibility mode will work.

In place of `MvcHtmlString` on .NET Standard, you can use the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString` type as per [this answer](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/178).

Since the base class of `MvcHtmlString` is `HtmlString` in .NET 4.0, you should return `HtmlString` and it will work in both cases (although you need to import a different namespace for each).

```
#if NET40
    using HtmlString = System.Web.HtmlString;
#else
    using HtmlString = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString;
#endif
```

You need a reference to [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions/) in your `netstandard2.0` targeted references to use that type.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net40</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net40' ">     
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

As for `ToHtmlString()`, I am confused what [Microsoft intends to do about it](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1164). However, adding an extension method between `#if NETSTANDARD2.0` and `#endif` blocks (or a file that is conditionally included for compile) is a pretty straghtforward thing to do in your library.

However, as John Skeet pointed out in the comments, it may not be the best idea to expose 2 different types through the same API like this. You might be better off making a separate APIs for .NET Framework and .NET Core and put them in separate platform-targeted libraries that reference a `.NET Standard` library containing the shared business logic.

Comment: And how can I make that change and still target the old net40?

Comment: I'm thinking I wont be able to do this because the library overrides the old MVC methods and they return MvcHtmlString.

Comment: It's using these methods [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: Note that if you're going to expose that `HtmlString` in your public API, this sort of "bait and switch" is a really bad idea. (Been there accidentally, done that.) It's not too bad if it's purely internal, but you'll need to be very careful to make sure that it doesn't leak.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Ok, what would you suggest as an alternative? We are all here to learn :).

Comment: We don't know enough about the scenario to suggest alternatives. It may not even be an issue. But creating a library where the public API exposes two different types depending on which framework you're targeting can cause big headaches.

Comment: The `HtmlHelper.DropDownListFor` returns MvcHtmlString and I'm not finding an alternative right now. Still searching. And I'm not sure if the `.net 4.0` project would understand `HtmlString`.

Comment: @fdbva - See the last paragraph. Jon is right, you should probably consider moving the business logic of these HTML helpers into a .NET Standard library and having a .NET Framework-targeted library that provides only MVC 5 APIs and a .NET Core-targeted library that provides only AspNetCore APIs (you might even opt for tag helpers instead of HTML helpers in that environment).

Comment: @NightOwl888 - After your explanation I understand the problem. I still don't know how to convert the `MvcHtmlString` returned by `DropDownListFor` that was originally using `.ToHtmlString()`. I'm trying to make a version that only targets `.net standard2.0` now. Everything in my control is using `HtmlString`, but the methods from `namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html` and class `SelectExtensions` still are a problem.

Comment: You can use net472 if your package has other .NET standard dependencies instead of net40