# Reference to type HtmlString claims it is defined in System.Web, but it could not be found

Tags: asp.net-core

I am on .NET Core 3.1. On creating a page in my application, i receive this error on build

```
Error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  CS7069  Reference to type 'HtmlString' claims it is defined in 'System.Web', but it could not be found      C:\xx\xxx\xxx\Views\Report\ListAllReports.cshtml 14
```

My razor view code with the error:

```
    @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model, page => Url.Action("Report","ListAllReports", new { page = page }),
    new X.PagedList.Mvc.Common.PagedListRenderOptions
    {
        DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true,
        ContainerDivClasses = new[] { "navigation" },
        LiElementClasses = new[] { "page-item" },
        PageClasses = new[] { "page-link" },
    })
```

I tried to upgrade from .NET 3.1 to 5.0 but i see the error still there.

Comment: Looks like you are using the wrong tags here as the `dot` tag is for the graphviz dot prohram.

Comment: I just changed that

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
X.PagedList.Mvc.Common.PagedListRenderOptions
```

indicates you are trying with the Package:

```
X.PagedList.Mvc
```

[image]

This package is for Asp.Net dependend on .net framework

> I am on .NET Core 3.1.

You should try with the package if you work on .net core:

```
X.PagedList.Mvc.Core
```

the full name of PagedListRenderOptions should be

```
X.PagedList.Web.Common.PagedListRenderOptions()
```

When it comes to the reason for the error,you could check this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48642257/converting-net4-0-old-library-to-multiple-targets-with-net-standard-2-0-gives)

Some of your library is depend on System.Web.HtmlString(.net framework) but in .net core  it should be (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString) check your packages if they have .net core version